# three.js rendering text to scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new at three.js.

In my work, I have to made 3d graphical website.

So after searched in google, I found that three.js is suitable to manipulate WebGL conveniently.

In three.js document(https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/TextGeometry),

TextGeometry is API for draw text in the scene.

[src.js]

```
init = () => {
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeWindow);
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
  var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
  controls.update();
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

  renderer.setClearColor(0xdd3b56);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Set shadow
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  // Show Axis
  var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(5);
  scene.add(axes);

  // Text
  var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
  loader.load( './helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {
      var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello three.js!', {
          font: font,
          size: 80,
          height: 5,
          curveSegments: 12,
          bevelEnabled: true,
          bevelThickness: 10,
          bevelSize: 8,
          bevelSegments: 5
      } );
  } );
  var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFE98A0});
  var text = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, textMaterial);
  text.position.x = 0;
  text.position.y = 10;
  text.position.z = 10;
  scene.add(text);

  // Light
  var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF);
  spotLight.position.set(-40, 60, 30);
  spotLight.castShadow = true;
  spotLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 5120;
  spotLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 5120;
  scene.add(spotLight);

  // Camera Setting
  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.y = 30;
  camera.position.z = 30;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
  document.getElementById("threejs_scene").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  renderScene();

  function renderScene() {
    requestAnimationFrame(renderScene);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
}
window.onload = init();
```

[index.html]

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="three.js"></script>
  <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="threejs_scene"></div>
  <script src="src.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I execute my code, it throws `[.WebGL-0x7fb612852000]RENDER WARNING: Render count or primcount is 0.` and `WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.` errors.

So I searched it at google, it occured when Three.js is trying to render an object that does not exist yet.

But in my code, I already defined it.

```
  var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFE98A0});
  var text = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, textMaterial);
  text.position.x = 0;
  text.position.y = 10;
  text.position.z = 10;
```

How can I solve this issue?

My last goal is display text in the scene.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that the first error in your console? Perhaps your font might is not loading properly?

Comment: @manthrax That is first error and another object displayed perfectly.

Comment: @manthrax I removed another object's code for readability.

Comment: @manthrax How can I check font is loaded or not? I save `helvetiker_regular.typeface.json` file in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function(params) {

  /*
   *
   * SET UP THE WORLD
   * 
   */



  //set up the ratio
  var gWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var gHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var ratio = gWidth / gHeight;
  var borders = [40, 24] //indicate where the ball needs to move in mirror position


  var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
  var light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
  light1.position.set(0, 5, 0);
  light1.castShadow = true;

  //  set the renderer 
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
  camera.position.set(10, 10, 10);
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  //properties for casting shadow
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

  renderer.setSize(gWidth, gHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.add(light);
  scene.add(light1);

  var ground = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 0.5, 10), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial())
  ground.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(ground)
  var geometry;


  var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
  var mesh;

  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  function render() {
    if (mesh) {
      mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
      mesh.rotation.z += 0.007;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  loader.load('https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function(font) {

    var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry('Hello three.js!', {
      font: font,
      size: 80,
      height: 5,
      curveSegments: 12,
      bevelEnabled: true,
      bevelThickness: 10,
      bevelSize: 8,
      bevelSegments: 5
    });

    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: 0xF3FFE2
    });
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.set(0, 2, 0);
    mesh.scale.multiplyScalar(0.01)
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(mesh);


    var canv = document.createElement('canvas')
    canv.width = canv.height = 256;
    var ctx = canv.getContext('2d')
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
    ctx.fillText("HERE IS SOME 2D TEXT", 20, 20);
    var tex = new THREE.Texture(canv);
    tex.needsUpdate = true;
    var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: tex
    });
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10), mat);
    scene.add(plane)
  });



}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I solved it with your code. But can you tell me where is the point that error occured?

Comment: I have no idea.. but my guess is that you're using an old version of three, or the font load is failing silently, since there is no error handler passed to it. What version of THREE are you loading? Where did you get your font file?

Comment: Latest version and font file is in same folder with `index.html` and `src.js`

Comment: I will find where is error occured. Anyway, do you know how to display text 2d? Above code's text displayed 3d.

Comment: For 2d, you draw your text to a canvas and then use the canvas as a texture on a plane.

Comment: Ok. I will check it. In my project, I have to display lots of text. So if I applied your code, is there any performance issue?

Comment: Yes. It depends on the size of your canvas(s), and how many strings you can pack into each canvas, and how often you have to change the text, and how many text planes you have.

If you want to do multiple text planes but not have a full canvas associated with each one, you'll probably need to modify the texture coordinates of the planes to map to each strings region on the canvas.

What are you trying to build?

Comment: Universe that has many texts. Similar to `https://50-jahre-hitparade.ch/`.

Comment: Cool. Yeah that looks like canvas textures.